# CKFinder; how to hide the settings icon

Tags: javascript, ckfinder

Does anyone know how to hide these 2 buttons for the latest ckfinder?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `FilesMoveCopy` and `Settings` Modules using [removeModules configuration](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-removeModules).

```
// Disable Move, Copy and Settings functionality:
config.removeModules = 'FilesMoveCopy,Settings';
```

However, if you wish to only remove buttons from toolbar you'd have to listen for [toolbar events](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-toolbar_reset_Main_file).

```
finder.on( 'toolbar:reset:Main:file', function( evt ) {
    var toRemove = evt.data.toolbar.filter( function( button ) {
        return button.get( 'name' ) === 'Settings';
    } );

    evt.data.toolbar.remove( toRemove );
}, null, null, 1000 );
```

Please note that there are 4 toolbar events:

- toolbar:reset:Main:file
- toolbar:reset:Main:files
- toolbar:reset:Main:folder
- toolbar:reset:Main:resources